# creating a coded alphabet

Tags: java, class, methods

I try to create a method that outputs a coded language including one alphabet and one digit(0-9) in java but I cant get the output!! the output should be like that: f3 g4 h5...e8
and the user enter the inputs for first letter and the integer!
initial values of letters and digits are provided from the main method class during the porject.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintCodeWord {
  private char firstLetter;
  private int integer;

  public PrintCodeWord(char firstLetter, int integer) {
    this.firstLetter = firstLetter;
    this.integer = integer;
  }

  public PrintCodeWord() {
  }

  public String toString() {
    return (firstLetter + " " + integer);
  }

  private int letterPart(char firstLetter) {
    switch (firstLetter) {
    case 'A':
        return 1;
    case 'B':
        return 2;
    case 'C':
        return 3;
    case 'D':
        return 4;
    case 'E':
        return 5;
    case 'F':
        return 6;
    case 'G':
        return 7;
    case 'H':
        return 8;
    case 'I':
        return 9;
    case 'J':
        return 10;
    case 'K':
        return 11;
    case 'L':
        return 12;
    case 'M':
        return 13;
    case 'N':
        return 14;
    case 'O':
        return 15;
    case 'P':
        return 16;
    case 'Q':
        return 17;
    case 'R':
        return 18;
    case 'S':
        return 19;
    case 'T':
        return 20;
    case 'U':
        return 21;
    case 'V':
        return 22;
    case 'W':
        return 23;
    case 'X':
        return 24;
    case 'Y':
        return 25;
    case 'Z':
        return 26;
    default:
        System.out.println("Fatal Error!");
        System.exit(0);
        return 00;
    }
  }

  public void onlyLetter() {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    for(i =letterPart(firstLetter)+1 ; i<27;i++)
    {
        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            char c1 = 'A';System.out.println(c1);break;
        case 2:
            char c2 = 'B';System.out.println(c2);break;
        case 3:
            char c3 = 'C';System.out.println(c3);break;
        case 4:
            char c4 = 'D';System.out.println(c4);break;
        case 5:
            char c5 = 'E';System.out.println(c5);break;
        case 6:
            char c6 = 'F';System.out.println(c6);break;
        case 7:
            char c7 = 'G';System.out.println(c7);break;
        case 8:
            char c8 = 'H';System.out.println(c8);break;
        case 9:
            char c9 = 'I';System.out.println(c9);break;
        case 10:
            char c10 = 'J';System.out.println(c10);break;
        case 11:
            char c11 = 'K';System.out.println(c11);break;
        case 12:
            char c12 = 'L';System.out.println(c12);break;
        case 13:
            char c13 = 'M';System.out.println(c13);break;
        case 14:
            char c14 = 'N';System.out.println(c14);break;
        case 15:
            char c15 = 'O';System.out.println(c15);break;
        case 16:
            char c16 = 'P';System.out.println(c16);break;
        case 17:
            char c17 = 'Q';System.out.println(c17);break;
        case 18:
            char c18 = 'R';System.out.println(c18);break;
        case 19:
            char c19 = 'S';System.out.println(c19);break;
        case 20:
            char c20 = 'T';System.out.println(c20);break;
        case 21:
            char c21 = 'U';System.out.println(c21);break;
        case 22:
            char c22 = 'V';System.out.println(c22);break;
        case 23:
            char c23 = 'W';System.out.println(c23);break;
        case 24:
            char c24 = 'X';System.out.println(c24);break;
        case 25:
            char c25 = 'Y';System.out.println(c25);break;
        case 26:
            char c26 = 'Z';System.out.println(c26);break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Fatal Error!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }

    }
    for (j = 1; j <= letterPart(firstLetter); j++)
    {
        switch (j) {
        case 1:
            char c1 = 'A';System.out.println(c1);break;
        case 2:
            char c2 = 'B';System.out.println(c2);break;
        case 3:
            char c3 = 'C';System.out.println(c3);break;
        case 4:
            char c4 = 'D';System.out.println(c4);break;
        case 5:
            char c5 = 'E';System.out.println(c5);break;
        case 6:
            char c6 = 'F';System.out.println(c6);break;
        case 7:
            char c7 = 'G';System.out.println(c7);break;
        case 8:
            char c8 = 'H';System.out.println(c8);break;
        case 9:
            char c9 = 'I';System.out.println(c9);break;
        case 10:
            char c10 = 'J';System.out.println(c10);break;
        case 11:
            char c11 = 'K';System.out.println(c11);break;
        case 12:
            char c12 = 'L';System.out.println(c12);break;
        case 13:
            char c13 = 'M';System.out.println(c13);break;
        case 14:
            char c14 = 'N';System.out.println(c14);break;
        case 15:
            char c15 = 'O';System.out.println(c15);break;
        case 16:
            char c16 = 'P';System.out.println(c16);break;
        case 17:
            char c17 = 'Q';System.out.println(c17);break;
        case 18:
            char c18 = 'R';System.out.println(c18);break;
        case 19:
            char c19 = 'S';System.out.println(c19);break;
        case 20:
            char c20 = 'T';System.out.println(c20);break;
        case 21:
            char c21 = 'U';System.out.println(c21);break;
        case 22:
            char c22 = 'V';System.out.println(c22);break;
        case 23:
            char c23 = 'W';System.out.println(c23);break;
        case 24:
            char c24 = 'X';System.out.println(c24);break;
        case 25:
            char c25 = 'Y';System.out.println(c25);break;
        case 26:
            char c26 = 'Z';System.out.println(c26);break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Fatal Error!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean " cant get the output". what *do* you get? what do you expect? what method is called?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output for several cases ?

Comment: I mean when I entered one alphabet and one digit from the keyboard, the program should be able to create the coded alphabet by mixing one alphabet and one digit.for example when I input D and 5 the program should out put D5  E6  F7  G8......X5   Y6......B9  C0